# How to find all regex strings in python dateparser

Tags: python, date-parsing

I am using `dateparser` modules to parse some human readable text to python date time objects. For now I am having a list of regex strings and applying on input strings to find out is there any matches.

I want to use full list of regex list that `dateparser` uses, is there way to get the list or is there a way to work on input string only.

I am having list like below

```
date_regex = ['[0-9]+ days', 'yesterday', '[0-9]+ weeks', 'a week', '1 week', 'last week', '[0-9]+ months', 'a month', '1 month', 'year']
```

but using `dateparser` can parse strings like `1 year ago`, `last 3 mins ago`. So I would like to take all available regex that `dateparser` using.

My input contains lot of text also included with date/time related strings as well. So I need to extract those and convert them into date time object using `dateparser`.

Update with example
`input="I booked a movie 4 days ago, but planned last week"`.
I need to extract `4 days ago` and `last week`. I thought of applying all available regex strings in `dateparser`.

Comment: I assume that you're using https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Yes, I am using that only.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the `dateparser` package? Parsing dates from natural language is pretty complex with lots of edge cases. If you are just curious what they are doing, the best way to find out is to look at the source code.

- [dateparser: date translation: en.json](https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser/blob/master/dateparser_data/cldr_language_data/date_translation_data/en.json)
- [dataparser: numeral translation: data en.json](https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser/blob/master/dateparser_data/cldr_language_data/numeral_translation_data/en.json)

Edit:

You can convert a list of strings into regexes:

```
import re
regexes = list(map(lambda x: re.compile(x), items))
```

Comment: Yeah I am looking in their source code that is there a method they have used to check user passed input string over their regex matcher.

Comment: @kishore is the question, how do you read a regex from file and then execute it on a variable?

Comment: I think the question is, "how do I use `dateparser`".

Comment: No I want to apply all possible regex on my input string to find any date/time related strings are there or not. if there convert them into date time object.

Comment: @kishore You can do that using the `dateparser` package. The details are in the readme.
https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser#usage